# Preciso de ajuda como faço para limitar ou equilibrar as cores de uma imagem com php

Tags: php, html

Preciso de ajuda com uma imagem. Quero sabe como faço para limitar as cores dela tipo 16 cores?

Exemplo:

Antes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria bom [edit] sua pergunta pondo um exemplo do que quer obter, explicar o que tentou e qual foi a dificuldade encontrada para que a comunidade possa ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Neste exemplo, você carrega uma imagem, jpg ou png, também carrega um gif(16cores), a imagem que você quer manipular copia as propriedades de cor do gif, salva uma nova e apaga todo mundo que nao terá utilidade, veja em que pontos voce vai interagir com as suas imagens, quais quer descartar e quais manter salvas. O gif de cores está anexado aqui. Voce ainda pode optar em salvar sua nova imagem em png ou jpg(se a ideia é reduzir alocação esta é mais leve).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$palette = imagecreatefromgif('palette-gif-03.gif');

$source = imagecreatefromjpeg('test-image-01.jpg');

$source_w = imagesx($source);
$source_h = imagesy($source);

$image = imagecreate($source_w, $source_h);

imagepalettecopy($image, $palette);

imagecopy($image, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $source_w, $source_h);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);

imagedestroy($imgage);
imagedestroy($palette);
imagedestroy($source);
?>
```